# Preview remote links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Anyone knows how can I preview links which are not saved locally on the server. I have read this [article](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/javascriptandajax/0321430328/ch15lev1sec5.html) about previewing links on the fly but it says its only working from local files.

I want to preview a link like http://www.google.com, etc. I was thinking i could use something similar to PHP's read function `file_get_contents` or that wouldn't do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$("#preview").hover()` event and create an iframe to preview them:

http://jsfiddle.net/mQhX5/1/

Adjust position and size depending on your need.

This is the css to resize the iframe content to make them small:

```
iframe {
    width: 800px;
    height: 520px;
    border: none;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```